# How to make a bitmap take less memory on Android?

Tags: android, bitmap

I have  a set of image files stored in internal storage, each file size is about 750 KB. I need to create a 360 degrees animation like with this images, so, I load each image in a list, while I'm doing this process an out of memory exception appears.
I have been reading about bitmap processing on Android, but in this case is not about resize bitmap dimensions, the dimensions are OK (600, 450) because its a tablet application, is about image quality I think.
Is there a way to reduce the memory each bitmap takes?.

Comment: If the image needs to be a 600x450 bitmap, you cannot reduce the file size.

Comment: Ok, so I think I have to optimize the images before use them in the application. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible without reducing image dimensions.

All images with the same dimensions require same amount of RAM, regardless it size on disk and compression. Graphics adapter don't understand different image types and compression and it needs only uncompressed raw array of pixels. And it size is constant

For example

`size = width * height * 4; // for RGBA_8888`

`size = width * height * 2; // for RGB_565`

So you should reduce image dimensions or use caching on the disk and remove bitmaps from the RAM that are currently invisible and reload from disk when needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great resource on how to do this here:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Basically you need to load a bitmap at a different resolution using these two functions:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

Then set the image as follows:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), 
    R.drawable.my_image_resource, 
    imageView.getWidth(), 
    imageView.getHeight()));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I already read this topic, the problem is not about reduce image dimensions, I just want to know if it was posible to reduce its quality. Thanks for your help.